# How to change default settings for volume and brightness keys?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, sound-volume, keybindings

One of the best Mac OS keyboard shortcuts I've discovered this past year is that by pressing SHIFT+OPTION while pressing the volume up/down keys or brightness up/down keys, the levels change in *quarter* increments instead of whole increments.

I find that I'm using this so often, that I'd now prefer the quarter increment change to become the default for these keys.  In an ideal scenario, for example, pressing the volume up key (without having to press SHIFT+OPTION) would increase volume by a quarter increment, and pressing the volume up key with SHIFT+OPTION would increase volume by a whole increment.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?  Someone pointed me towards the Karabiner-Elements keyboard remapping software, but I'm not sure if that's the right approach here or if it would even work.